# Positive definite self-adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator in V and $A=[T]_B$ where $B$ s an orthonormal basis of $V$.

So, I have to prove that $T$ is positive definite if and only if $L_A$ is positive definite.

I haven't tried much since I don't really known where to start. I've proven that $T$ is definite positive if and only if all its eigen values are positive, but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: Can you say what $T_B$ is.  Also, what is $L_A$.  Is T linear? You haven't said much about V -- can we assume it is not finite dimensional?  It is true that any operator is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive; it's one of several equivalent definitions of positive definite in a finite dimensional space.  In an infinite dim space there may not be any eigenvalues; you would need T bounded.

Comment: $[T]_B$ is the matrix asociated to T in the basis B. $L_A(x)=Ax$. T is linear and V is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite operator. Fix an orthonormal basis
$\left\{ e_{j}\right\} $ in V. For all $v=\sum v_{j}e_{j}$, 
$$
\sum_{ij}v_{i}\overline{v_{j}}\left\langle Ae_{i},e_{j}\right\rangle =\left\langle Av,v\right\rangle \geq0.
$$
Thus, the matrix of $A$, i.e., $\left(\left\langle Ae_{i},e_{j}\right\rangle \right)_{ij}$,
is positive definite.